# input range instance variable returns the initial value and it not the modified

Tags: javascript, html, class, input

i stored the value of 2 input range into an instance variable on a class, but in the first one `pow` it works and in the second one `ang` it returns always 0. Actually even if i change the values they do not store the just modified value but the initial one.

I can't really understand why.

Here is the code:

```js
let c;
let b;

function startGame() {
  c = new Console();
  b = new Bullet();
}

class Console {
  constructor() {
    this.ang = document.getElementById("angle");
    this.p = document.getElementById("power");
  }

  pow() {
    powRange.value = this.p.value;
  }

  deg() {
    degRange.value = this.ang.value;
  }
}

class Bullet {
  constructor() {
    this.a = parseInt(c.p.value);
    this.alpha = parseInt(c.ang.value);
  }

  log() {
    console.log(this.a);
    console.log(this.alpha);
  }
}

//CONSOLE
startGame();
let degRange = document.querySelector('.displayAngle');
let powRange = document.querySelector('.displayPower');
let check1 = /^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$/;
let check2 = /^(?:36[0]|3[0-5][0-9]|[12][0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])?$/;
c.pow();
c.deg();

powRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (!check1.test(powRange.value)) {
    powRange.value = '';
  } else {
    c.p.value = powRange.value;
  }
});

degRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (!check2.test(degRange.value)) {
    degRange.value = '';
  } else {
    c.ang.value = degRange.value;
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  b.log();
}, 5000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

input[type="range"]:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #39CCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #39CCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.console {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

label {
  padding: 3px;
}

input[type="range"] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.form-a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-a>div {
  display: flex;
}

.form-a>div>p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-p>div {
  display: flex;
}

.display {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  outline-width: 0;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="console">
  <div class="form-p">
    <label>Power</label>
    <div>
      <input id="power" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" oninput="c.pow()" />
      <input class="display displayPower" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-a">
    <label>Angolation</label>
    <div>
      <input id="angle" type="range" oninput="c.deg()" value="0" max="360" />
      <input class="display displayAngle" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're setting `this.a` and `this.alpha` on the `Bullet` constructor class. So at the time you set these variables the value of `c.ang.value` is `0`.

So to make your code work you must set your `Bullet` properties in the log function, like this:

```
class Bullet {
   constructor() {}
   log() {
       this.a = parseInt(c.p.value);
       this.alpha = parseInt(c.ang.value);
       console.log(this.a);
       console.log(this.alpha);
   }
}
```